# Filling unknowns within a sequence with a sequence-to-sequence LSTM model

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, hidden-markov-model, sequential-pattern-mining

Say we have a very simple sequence pattern that associates a state which is always observable, with a state that is sometimes hidden, and that we want to predict when it's hidden. It is assumed that the sometimes-hidden state is dependent on the observable state, both current and past/future.

For example, if we track the sequence of pickup/delivery that a truck performs over time, along with which city the operation takes place:

```
date    city          operation
-------------------------------
Jan-01  New York      Pickup
Jan-02  Atlanta       Delivery
Jan-03  Chicago       Pickup
Jan-04  Denver        Pickup
Jan-05  New York      Delivery
Jan-06  Boston        Delivery
Jan-07  Philadelphia  Delivery
```

Let's assume that there is a real pattern to it and that, for instance, most of the time, when the truck picks up at New York and the visits Philadelphia, it will do a delivery there (instead of picking up more stuff).

Sometimes, the data that we observe is the following:

```
city        operation
----------------------
New York       Pickup
Philadelphia   [Unknown]
Denver         Pickup
Chicago        [Unknown]
New York       Pickup
Atlanta        Delivery
New York       [Unknown]
Boston         Delivery
```

In this case, I would like the model to be able to fill in the blanks and predict the most likely operation between `pickup` and `delivery`.

Assuming the data points where we can observe both the city and the operation are in the millions, would an LSTM be an appropriate model in this case? How would one go about training such a model? Would we just feed a sequence of `[city, operation]` with some kind of random mask on the `operation` and then have the model output the sequence of `[city, operation]` that it sees as most likely?

Lastly, would it be possible to obtain a probability estimation of different possible `operation` for a given entry, such as `{pickup: 56%, delivery: 44%}` ?